# Loop through array and copy the element selected in html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I took this code snippet off the W3 school and want to change it slightly.  I've got an html user form that I would like to load all the array elements into.  Then utilizing the `onClick` event from the form (drop down list) i would like to be able to copy that element to the clipboard.

```js
<script>
var fruits, text, fLen, i;
fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;

text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
  <select id="cars" name="cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your form so you want to load into ?

Comment: here is the code for the form.  generic.

Comment: What I am hoping to end up with is load the array into the form, the user clicks on the element and the clicked element copied to the clipboard for pasting in another web page.  I know the top jscript loops thru all the elements but I dont know how to make the two parts work together.